# Laravel have Two foreign Key from the same table

Tags: laravel, database-design, database-migration

Hi I am not very good with Database Design so I would like to know if it's possible to create a table with two foreign key from the same table.

this is my effort on trying to show the relationship
[image]

is it possible for me to do this using laravel migration I have tried but it's not working

```
Schema::create('events', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('event_id');
        $table->integer('book_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('buyers_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('seller_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('status')->default(1);
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('book_id')->references('id')
        ->on('books')
        ->onDelete('cascade')
        ->onUpdate('cascade');
        $table->foreign('buyers_id')->references('id')
        ->on('users')
        ->onDelete('cascade')
        ->onUpdate('cascade');
        $table->foreign('seller_id')->references('id')
        ->on('users')
        ->onDelete('cascade')
        ->onUpdate('cascade');
    });
```

so the event table will have 3 FK

- one FK from Books
- two FK from Users

  ```
   Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->increments('id');

      $table->string('name')->unsigned();

      $table->integer('user_type');

      $table->integer('password');

      $table->timestamps();


  });
  ```

this is the schema of users table

Comment: why not making single column `buyer_seller_id` and giving them roles as `buyer` and `seller`?

Comment: in the users table?

Comment: foreign key in `events` table and `role` in `users` table

Comment: ok like this in Users (name, user_type, "role_id", and password)

Comment: yes and adding their ids in events table as per the requirement

Comment: currently: events table's 'buyers_id' and 'sellers_id'  references the users table's 'id', I should change reference to 'role_id' ?

Comment: No what i am saying is that make column `role_id` in users table for ex `1 for buyer` and `2 for seller` and make column `buyer_seller_id` in `events` table it will reference to `id` in `users` table. you will differentiate user by getting `role_id` to check if the user is buyer or seller

Comment: You said "but it isn't working". What is the error shown?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If in your application your User can act both as a seller and a buyer, the `role_id` solution proposed in the comments of your quest will not work for you.

Following the solution you were already working on, it not seems to have anything wrong with your migrations, when you run `php artisan migrate` is it showing any error? If you post it, I can update this part of my response.

In the Event model, you have to describe the relationships like this:

```
public function buyer()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'buyers_id');
}

public function seller()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'seller_id');
}
```

So when you use your Event model, you can do it like this

```
$event = new Event;
$event->buyers_id = 1; // supposing there's a user with id 1
$event->seller_id = 2; // supposing there's a user with id 2
$event->save();

$event->buyer;
# => <User::class id=1>
$event->seller;
# => <User::class id=2>
```

---

**[UPDATE] Add a little tip**

Not related to your question, but I suggest you rename your `buyers_id` column to `buyer_id`. It's a common practice to keep your foreign keys name in the singular in Laravel.

---

**[UPDATE] Link to the docs**

For full documentation on the relationship' methods.

– https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse

Comment: Thanks, if i could. to access Event from User model $this->hasMany('App\Event', 'buyers_id'); and $this->hasMany('App\Event', 'seller_id');

Comment: it is getting a problem when accessing the seller and buyer attributes like name